# Dynamic height for react-native-swiper component

Tags: react-native

He, I am using the [`react-native-swiper`](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper)component to display an image slideshow.

Currently I am specifying the `height` attribute for the `Swiper` component, but I would like to make the `height` dynamic, depending on the size of the images displayed in the swiper.

In my case the images are quadratic and the height is determined by its width. So all the images displayed by the swiper do have the same height.

My current Swiper (with the fixed height) looks like:

```html
<Swiper autoplay height={375}>
            {bounty.pictures.map((item, key) => {
              return (
                <View key={key}>
                  <Image styleName="large-square" source={{ uri: item.image }}></Image>
                </View>
              )
            })}
</Swiper>
```

When I do not specify any `height` in the current implementation, the `Swiper` component is roughly double the size of the underlying image.

I could not find any `react-native-swiper` examples that use a dynamic height depending on the content displayed.

Comment: Looks like [this PR](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper/pull/343) will solve the issue.

Comment: Indeed! Anyone able to push that PR to be merged?

Comment: Have you found any solution yet ?